# Rename multiple files part serial numbers part equal string in R

Tags: r

I have several files (19x11x4) i'd need rename sequentially (1:19) plus incrementing the same string at all of them.

The first files are named this way:

```
cc26bi701 
cc26bi702
cc26bi703
```

They need them to be called:
bio1
bio2
bio3

My failed attempt was

```
files <- list.files(list.files("./data/gs26bi70",  pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)
sapply( seq_along(files),function(x){
 file.rename(files[x], paste0("bio")))
})
```

Regards,

Comment: `paste0("bio")` is just `"bio"` every time. You need to reference `x` as well I imagine - `paste0("bio", x)`

Comment: Thanks thalatemail, you were wright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@thelatemail's comment is correct. `paste0()` needs at least 2 strings.

You also have the problem that the file names in `files` all end in `.tif`, and you want to keep this file extension at the end.

This uses your basic idea, just simplified a little.

```
myPath <- './/data//gs26bi70//'
fileList <- dir(path = myPath, pattern = '*.tif')  # list of file names, not including their paths

sapply(X = fileList, FUN = function(x) {
  file.rename(paste0(myPath, x),     # paste0() the path and old name
              paste0(myPath, 'bio', substring(x, first = 8))) })     # paste0() the path and new name

# substring('hello world', first = 8) returns 'orld'
# (starting at number 8, all following characters are returned)
```

`file.rename()` requires 2 strings: the path and old file name, and the path and new file name. We provide the path and old file name using `paste0(myPath, x)` (where `x` is the name of the file we are currently renaming). Then, we provide the same path, but we join it with `'bio'`, and the last 6 characters of the old name. We use the `substring()` function to get the last characters of the old file name. So in your question, you say one of the files is named `cc26bi701.tif`. From this, we pull off `01.tif` and add it to the end of `bio` to get `bio01.tif`.

*Note: I used the last 6 characters of the old file name instead of using `seq_along()` to name them sequentially because I was not sure of the order in which `R` would sort them. For example, if we renamed the `cc26bi701.tif` file last, its new name would be `bio19.tif`, when it should be renamed `bio01.tif`. Hopefully I am correct in this assumption.*

Comment: Thanks Sam, it works! I just had to change "first = 8" to "first =9" because inside the origin folder that are some files ending in tow decimal cases (gs26bi79 as well gs26bi710). So when i leave "first = 8" all files were renamed keeping the 0 caracter (bio01, bio02, bio010, bio011). Thant change ir your suggestion solves the problem. Thank you!